# cvd process in linux

Tags: linux, cpu, process, redhat-enterprise-linux

i'm getting a problem with my redhat system, its very slow and when i checked the system i found `cvd` process taking all my cpu

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 2044 root      20   0  990m  14m  10m S 83.3  0.1 101543:47 cvd
 1626 root      20   0  206m  36m 4632 S  8.1  0.3   2878:07 vmtoolsd
 2177 root      20   0  875m  71m  61m S  3.9  0.6   1389:15 EvMgrC
```

what does this `cvd` and is it harmful to kill it ?

Comment: It is [Commvault](https://www.commvault.com/).

Comment: What do you mean by "lent"?

Comment: slow*, my bad, lent in frensh means slow